# Failed to initialize Open CTI. Ensure that it is loaded from the right frame with correct URL parameters

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, visualforce-component, opencti

I'm trying to use an existing web page that's using Open CTI to emulate Softphone screen popping and using Apex together with Lightning. I'm trying to do this by having it inside a Utiliy Bar component.

The old implementation uses sforce.interaction.runApex functions which I've changed to sforce.opencti as they do not work with Lightning.

First I attempted to create a new Lightning component with an iframe with the url to my implementation so that I can display it. This is successful up to the point where any sforce functions are called. I use callbacks for sforce.opencti.runApex for example and they return nothing.

Then I attempted to re-create my web page as a Visualforce page and include the link to that into the iframe. When I open my Utility bar component, it displays my page but in the console I get:

**Failed to initialize Open CTI. Ensure that it is loaded from the right frame with correct URL parameters**

The way I include Open CTI into my apex:page is as follows:

```
<apex:page >
   <head>
       <script src="https://<myDomain>/support/api/42.0/lightning/opencti_min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
   </head>
   <!-- The rest of my content -->
</apex:page>
```

**Question**

Why is it that Open CTI fails to initialize when I include it even though the file is there? Is there something extra I should be including?